# Using percentages for heights with children of "flex-grow:1 parent" not working

Tags: css, flexbox, height, percentage

My parent div `#box2` has a defined width, but it's height is left up to `flex-grow:1`. The problem is, any child within `#box2` cannot use percentages for heights because I guess `#box2`'s height isn't explicitly stated.

What can I do?

https://jsfiddle.net/tdje2tL1/1/

Comment: try setting the `#box2`'s height to 100%.

Comment: Since `#box2` doesn't have a height, `#box3` will resolve to `0`. Use nested flex elements: https://jsfiddle.net/tdje2tL1/20/

Comment: Since I can't answer, [here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/82t2t5Lf/) that will show you how to do it !